# How to get relative source of item in ItemTemplate

Tags: binding, datatemplate, relativesource

I have a ListBox with specified ItemTemplate. And the ItemTemplate contain itself ListView and I want to display in that ListView a collection, which is actually a property of the item of the ListBox.

Could you show me how to do Binding. I'm thinking about RelativeSource thing, but I don't know what correct syntax would look like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer.

it should be like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                     AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=DataContext.YourCollectionProperty}
```